# Redirect stdout and stderr to the output debug console of microsoft visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

I am using microsoft visual studio to do C++.
I don't see std::err and std::out in the output console of the IDE.
Is there a way to redirect them ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can indeed redirect std::out and std::err.  Simply right click on your project in the solution explorer and select `Properties`.  Then select `Configuration Properties -> Debugging` and put the appropriate arguments into the `Command Arguments` field.  For example, to redirect std::err to a file, I would type in `2> ErrorLog.txt`.

The things you type in `Command Arguments` simply get appended as command line arguments when Visual Studio runs your program, just like you had manually typed them in to the console.  So, the above example simply tells VisualStudio to run your program with the command `<programName>.exe 2> ErrorLog.txt` instead of just `<programName>.exe`.

Comment: Sorry my aim was to redirect the std::out and std::err to the output window of visual studio, not to a file. Thanks anyway

Comment: @jules No problem.  But, the title of the question is such that people just looking to redirect output might end up here as well, so I figured it would be worth posting this answer as well.

Comment: @Brandon Is it `>2` or `2>`?

Comment: It should be 2>filename.txt.  If I understand things correctly, >2 would redirect stdout to a file named '2' because it defaults to redirecting stdout if you don't specify a file descriptor before the >.  See [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) for more info on IO redirection.

Answer (score 7):

What you can do is redirect the *cout* to a *ostringstream* of your choice. To do this, derive a new class from *streambuf* that will send the stream to *OutputDebugString* (Lets call this class *OutputDebugStream*) and create an instance of the class, *myStream*. Now call:

```
cout.rdbuf(&myStream)
```

I used *cout* for an example. This same technique can be used with *cerr*, just call

```
cerr.rdbuf(&myStream).
```

*Stdout* is a little more difficult if you are not using *cout*. You can redirect *stdout* during runtime by using `freopen()`, but it must be to a file.  To get this to redirect to the Debug screen is a little more difficult.  One way is to use `fmemopen()` if it is available (it is not standard) and write a *streambuf* to output this data to the Debug screen.  Alternatively, you can redirect to a file and write a stream to open as input and redirect to the debug stream.  A bit more work, but I think it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following macro for output to the visual studio console

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <opencv/cxcore.h>

#define DBOUT( s )            \
{                             \
     std::wostringstream os_;    \
     os_ << s;                   \
     OutputDebugStringW( os_.str().c_str() );  \
}
#else
#define DBOUT( s )            \
{                             \
     std::cout << s;            \
}
#endif
```

Now if I could only get it to work within a cuda kernel?!