# How to display standard output in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Most IDE's I've seen (NetBeans, QtCreator, XCode, CodeBlocks, Eclipse) provide an out-of-the-box method to view standard output either in one of its embedded window or external console or in a log BUT Visual Studio.

I really don't want to *allocate a separate console* as it is suggested at [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840942/visual-studio-2012-c-standard-output) question. I'd also prefer not to redirect it to a file as it is suggested at [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683249/redirect-stdout-and-stderr-to-the-output-debug-console-of-microsoft-visual-studi) question (output file is not created with the suggested console command (`2>output.txt`)). **Please don't give answers that modify the codebase**  like using `OutputDebugString`.

If displaying standard output inside VS this way is not possible, a working solution of the other two alternatives would still be welcomed, namely using external console (which I tried using without seeing the output in it) or a log file.

Comment: Modify which codebase please what? Clarify your question please!

Comment: Without modifying any part of the source code, simply.

Comment: Which source code? Did you show any in your question? (Note that links don't count)

Comment: Why do I have to show source code if I'd want to avoid modifying any source code whatsoever? (this includes .h, .cpp files)

Comment: It's not the IDE, it's the way Windows programs work. By default there is either a console or a graphics window, not both.

Comment: @πάντα-ῥεῖ - He's got a program he wants to run under Visual Studio.  He wants to see stdout.  You don't need to see the code for the program.

Comment: I would say if you do not want to allocate a console for a GUI application or change the code or use /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE you are out of luck.

Comment: I'd want to use /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE, I tried too (this I aliased as "external console" in my question), without success. If you could point me in the direction how to make this work with that method I'd be very thankful.

Comment: @MatrixAndrew To be clear:  Do you have a program which starts at `main` or at `WinMain`?  If the former, I get stdout displayed in a separate console; if the latter, Windows (not Visual Studio) typically sends stdout to a black hole.

Comment: entry point looks like this: http://pastebin.com/6WyHcAKc

Comment: Did you try the editbin method in my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13841522/487892

Comment: Then that is your problem.  Windows is sending your stdout to a black hole.  If you want a graphics window and a console, you will have to change the code to create a console.

Comment: @drescherjm As a last resort I may try to use that method, but I'm still in shock due to the realization why one would need to do something like this manually when all other IDE's provide this functionality out-of-the-box.

Comment: Like others mentioned you are fighting windows on that. It's not really the IDE that is the problem.

Comment: Also I was hoping with VS2015 something has changed that enables what I'd seek. I'm fighting with a Windows on a lot of fronts, I recently spent half a day debugging environment variables because the existence of whitespaces after semicolons screws up the entire parsing of the variable paths.

Comment: Simple answer is VS2015 does not have this feature.

Comment: @MatrixAndrew With those other IDE's other than VS, what if a developer does *not* want the IDE to do these things, because possibly the developer is writing code that allocates a console window?  That would be confusing as heck...

Comment: Thank you for responses then, I'll probably go with the method that works with the previous versions as well then, allocating a console. I'd appreciate if you'd balance the score of my question to at least 0, because it is a legitimate question and I get prolonging existential crisis when I get downvotes.

Comment: @drescherjm In your answer a macro "_O_TEXT" is used, it is not defined in the MSVC library <io.h> like the rest and neither can I find anything about it on the net. Have they removed this recently? Is there an alternative way?

Comment: The documentation for _open_osfhandle describes these parameters: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdts1c9x.aspx

Comment: <fcntl.h> had to be included too, all compiles and I get the console but so far cout and cerr does not output into it  w/wo debugger (I use your openConsole() method as global function) I'll keep trying

Comment: No success. So only way left is if I convert this into a non-win32 application by creating a regular int main() entry point, too bad it's probably not possible with this project, well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is only for debugging purposes, you might find [Debug Breakpoints/Tracepoint actions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/232dxah7(v=vs.90).aspx) helpful.
They enable to log custom strings with expressions (i.e. variables) to the visual studio console.

For a non-console windows application, by default (i.e. without changing your codebase, as you are requesting) all output to stdout is lost..

Comment: That might come in handy too.